# Making a copy of a database using only SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I would like to make a copy of a source database SDB onto a newly created database TDB without using the traditional backup commands, but only via SQL. This would grant that:

1. If SDB has recovery mode=full, and TDB has recovery mode=simple,
   there would not be a lot of space wasted.
2. If I wanted to share a backup with a partner, I could delete some
   sensitive data from SDB, perform the copy, and I would be sure that
   there no part of the deleted data can ever be found in TDB by a
   hacker.

Is there a toolproduct to perform this action?
Ideally, I would like to be fully automatic. It would be ok if it takes a few hours for a database of 50 GB.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85080/discussion-on-question-by-carlo-borreo-making-a-copy-of-a-database-using-only-sq).

Answer (score 1):

Backup/Restore will suffice as a backup will only be made of allocated pages so any deleted data not having been cleaned up by the ghost cleanup will not be included in the backup. There are still reasons why you would want to generate scripts that will recreate the database and insert all the data like the database dump files in MySQL.

The generate script wizard will do that for you. In the SSMS right click the database and select Tasks, Generate Scripts and use the wizard until you come to the Saving screen when you need to press the Advanced button

[image: Specify how scripts should be saved or published]

There you need to at least change under general that you would like to script "Schema and data" and in general review the options. Then finish the wizard and you will have generated a text dump of the database.

[image]

You can [automate this using Powershell](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/automated-script-generation-with-powershell-and-smo/) or by calling the [SMO objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483568/how-can-i-automate-the-generate-scripts-task-in-sql-server-management-studio-2/7750466#7750466) and there are also number of third party tools to aid with scripting

Comment: Technically, this does not fit the question. That is a GUI, not the sql.

Comment: >>>Schema and data<<< is questionable when your db is about 1Tb. Besides, when you have a lot of FK be sure that generated script will not respect the order in which the tables are populating so it can generate a lot of errors when loading data